# A issue of concatenating two strings with if...else statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I tried to concatenate two string like this

```
print 'AAA' if True else 'BBB' + 'CCC' if True else 'DDD'
```

In terminal, it just print like this 'AAA' but not 'AAACCC'. Why? Is there any other alternative way?

Comment: You should really consider not using `+` string concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` has a higher [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than a conditional expression.

As a result, your expression is grouped like this:

```
('AAA') if (True) else (('BBB' + 'CCC') if (True) else ('DDD'))
```

You need to use parentheses to override the precedence:

```
print ('AAA' if True else 'BBB') + ('CCC' if True else 'DDD')
```

Demo:

```
>>> print 'AAA' if True else 'BBB' + 'CCC' if True else 'DDD'
AAA
>>> print 'AAA' if False else 'BBB' + 'CCC' if True else 'DDD'
BBBCCC
>>> print ('AAA' if True else 'BBB') + ('CCC' if True else 'DDD')
AAACCC
```